# Jpa Repository SaveAll Going Very Slow

Tags: sql-server, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, batch-processing

I working on a spring batch process where I am working with chunks of 1000 items at a time.

In my write method I am creating an entity for each item and then using a jpa repository like below and its saveAll method to save the entire chunk

```
@Repository
public interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<ExampleEntity, Integer> {
}
```

Problem is it is going way too slow. I am working through about 150,000 records in total and its taking about 2 and a half minutes per 1000 item chunk.

In my application.yml I have the following properties set

```
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
      jdbc:
        batch_size: 1000
```

Is there any other way to make this go faster?

Comment: Please share your item writer. Any reason not using the `RepositoryItemWriter`? FYI, some performance improvements were introduced in that writer in v4.3: https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/26/spring-batch-4-3-0-m1-is-released-now

Comment: There are hundreds of pieces that could be affecting your performance from database latency, networking, transaction overheads, connection pools etc to your object model itself. You'll need to do a lot more digging and experimenting, and in the end, there won't likely be one smoking gun or configuration setting; there really isn't a go fast button in performance tunning.

Comment: Take a look at the speeds and timings involved in inserting a single object, one per transaction and average it out, and then look at the numbers here with what I assume is 150k in the same transaction. Maybe break the 150k into smaller transactions, with 50k per transaction and commit, and see how it affects your numbers. Also try larger batches than 1000, smaller batches etc. With that data, and profiling of the different steps (datasource timing stats, etc) you might get a handle on where and why this isn't as fast as you'd like and have the data to tune it for your app.